# Read only specific lines from text file and save matches into variables

Tags: bash, text-processing

I've got this problem.

I need to extract some words from text file, which I find by specific pattern in that text. For example:

```
/this/is/path:
file1.txt,date-3
file2.txt,date-2
/this/is/path2:
file.txt,date-1
file2.txt,date-5
```

The pattern would be the `/path:` and to choose only lines after that and before another `/path:`. Because there might be the same names of files. And I need to find exact `file.txt` and take those 3 things:

- file
- date
- number of launch

into 3 variables.

Example:
I have text document in format:

```
/home/name/Documents:
file.txt,12.5.2014-1
file2.txt,15.8.2014-2
/home/name/Music:
file.txt,15.4.2014-2
f2ile3.txt,8.2.2015-5
file2.txt,7.6.2014-3
/home/name/Video:
file.txt,date-5
```

and there is directory music and documents which have same files and I want to chose from music only, file.txt. But when it will look for file.txt it will also find one in directory Documents so I only want to choose ones between directory music and it will end in directory Video. And when it finds the file.txt it will save it like this: 1.variable=file.txt, 2.variable=15.4.2014,3.variable=2.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand if you could give an example..

Comment: What do you mean by “number of launch”? What is “file1.txt date 3” — I understand that you mean that there is a file `/this/is/path/file1.txt`, but what is that “date 3” bit?

Comment: that there are 3 information about file and that's name, date when it was edited and how many times it was launched

Comment: If the file contains empty lines between the sections, please [edit] and clarify. That makes a huge difference and would greatly simplify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F'[,-]' '
  /Music/ {f=1} 
  /^$/ {f=0} f && /file\.txt/ \
  {printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", "var1="$1,"var2="$2,"var3="$3}
  ' file
var1=file.txt
var2=15.4.2014
var3=2
```

...assuming that there are, in fact, empty lines between your blocks (as per the first example).